# E-Mail Preview template cut Magento 2

Tags: email, magento2.4

When I create a transactional e-mail via Marketing --> E-Mail Templates and then click "Preview" my preview window is somehow being cut to a preview_iframe which only covers like 1/5th of the full page and I need to scroll in order to see the full e-mail preview.

Does anyone have an idea how and where I can edit this, so e-mail preview is showing on full page?